# ServiceState not detecting output_keys

Tags: rospy, smach

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using SMACH to request a Service. I want to assign a response callback that parses the Server's response and computes some output values.

Here there is the most relevant part of the code simplified for better understanding:

```
# hri result callback
def foo_response_cb(userdata, response):
  userdata.foo_var_out  = response.x + response.y
  return 'succeeded'

# add state to state machine
smach.StateMachine.add('FOO',
                      ServiceState('/service',
                                    myService,
                                    response_cb=foo_response_cb,
                                    output_keys=['foo_var_out']),
                      remapping={'foo_var_out':'sm_var'},
                      transitions={'succeeded':'succeeded'})
```

For some reason, the output values are not detected, so I get the following error:

> > Writing to SMACH userdata key 'foo_var_out' but the only keys that were declared as output from this state were: ().

Which is the same error I get if I do not add any output key at all.

Can anybody give some hint of what may be happening?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12960/servicestate-not-detecting-output_keys/) by [joan](https://answers.ros.org/users/881/joan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 245 on 2012-02-09

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [phil0stine](https://answers.ros.org/users/639/phil0stine/) on 2012-03-20**:
+1 for documenting your experiences with smach http://wikiri.upc.es/index.php/IRI_ROS_smach_guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This has been fixed with this revision, and a regression test has been added:
https://kforge.ros.org/smach/executive_smach/rev/f3611457d263

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1